# Lost queues at Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

This morning I found that my rabbitmq instances does not have several queues that are usually there.

What I noticed is a pattern, that the remaining queues are the ones that had consumers attached to those.

The queues that are gone are mostly retry and DLQs. How does one investigate what happened? What do I look for and where?

**Update:**

This is my queue details :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a feature of [TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) or Time to Live for a queue .

As shown in this example below

[image]

The value against **expires** correspond to 28 days. So If a queue hasn't had any consumer for 28 days it gets deleted.

It could also be possible that the [auto-delete](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html) property is set to true in which case the queue will automatically get deleted the moment the last consumer gets disconnected.

You should be able to get both these parameters in the rabbitmq console where you check the queue properties .

Comment: hi @Soumen Mukherjee do you think some of the properties set on the queue are causing it to just drop? I see the TTL, but message TTL. Also there is expires property, is it in MS? Does it mean queue is expiring in like 3 days?

Answer (score 2):

The `expires` is your problem there, if the queue has not been used for some time, it will get dropped.

Also I would get rid of the `message-ttl` unless you want your messages to be dropped after certain amount of time.

More info here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

These are rabbitmq configuration settings you must change, here some more info https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html